# Inject airflow variable in to tasks

Tags: python, orchestration

Is there a method to incorporate Airflow variables into task instances? These variables are defined in the administrative section of the user interface (UI).

tried on airflow ui

something like below:

```
configs = {
    "config1": {"message": "first DAG will receive this message"},
    "config2": {"message": "second DAG will receive this message"},
}

for config_name, config in configs.items():
    dag_id = f"dynamic_generated_dag_{config_name}"

    @dag(dag_id=dag_id, start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 1))
    def dynamic_generated_dag():
        @task
        def print_message(message):
            print(message)

        print_message(config["message"])

    dynamic_generated_dag()
```